# The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.8' was not found. with docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a project compiling with .net core 2.1

The project is very simple:

```
Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I have these two libraries reference:
[image]

It compiles and runs properly on the host.

I made a docker image:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build

COPY ./Test /src/Test
WORKDIR /src/Test
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app --no-restore

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

CMD ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

It builds properly, no warnings.

But when I execute it:

```
# dotnet Test.dll
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.1' was not     found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
  /usr/share/dotnet/
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

So, when I check the framework version (I build with dotnet:2.1-runtime):

```
# dotnet --info

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.8
  Commit:  209f8aa25c

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

So it looks like 2.1.8 is installed and somehow, it can't do the role of 2.1.1.

I tried two things:

- update my libs to version 2.1.8... then it can't find version 2.1.8 of the asp lib
- not put any version requirement in the csproj file and it can't find the asp lib either

How to get this working?

Comment: Your docker files look ok to me, as I'm using almost an identical set (using the dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime and sdk instead of the base dotnet one).

Answer (score 1):

I found that when using ASP, you can’t use the .net core image and add asp libraries.

You need to take the .net core asp docker image.